# Where is this environment variable set?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, environment-variables

Whenever I open a terminal I have this variable set:

```
$ echo $http_proxy
http://127.0.0.1:8888/
```

Where is this variable being set? I've checked `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/environment` and it's nowhere there?!

I've also looked at System Settings in the network section and the proxy is empty.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For `bash` run:

```
PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7> /tmp/mylog
```

then use

```
grep "http_proxy=" /tmp/mylog
```

to search for it.

You can also limit the search to `/home` and `/etc` for a better result:

```
$ grep "http_proxy=" /tmp/mylog | grep -e /home -e /etc
++/home/ravexina/.bashrc> http_proxy=http://test:80
```

which means it has been set in my `~/.bashrc`.

*[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154971/64321)*

Answer (score 7):

According to essentially [the duplicate of what you asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/813/85039) on [Unix & Linux site](https://unix.stackexchange.com), there are couple of ways to approach this problem:

1. use `env` command and observe the order in which variables were created, and use preceding and next variables to get rough idea of where the variable may have come from
2. wrap files which you try to investigate with `set -x` command in the beginning and end of the file to see what each file does; potentially those files are sourcing other files, and `set -x` should explicitly state where sourcing occurs
3. Consider going through some of the files you may have in your home folder via `find -type f -exec grep 'VARIABLE_NAME' {} \;` or just `grep -rI 'VARIABLE'`. This is time consuming , so might not be the best result, but hey - if there's no easy methods, one shouldn't put aside the hard ones.
4. Run `strace -v -s 10000 -e execve,open,read bash` and observer what is being read and what is the preceding `open()` call. This might be useful with `2&>1 >  output_trace.txt` redirection to read later and maybe `grep`. [Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83119/85039)
5. You mentioned .bashrc, .bash_profile, /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/environment. You also need to check:

   - `/etc/profile`
   - `/etc/profile.d/*`
   - `~/.profile` (only if you don't have a `~/.bash_profile`)
   - `~/.bash_login`
6. According to [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/proxy_settings), some programs like `wget` use this variable. Check if you might have `.wgetrc` or `/etc/wgetrc` file.  This might be set there, although where it gets sourced into `bash` is another mystery

Answer (score 0):

`gnome-terminal` itself (that is, this behavior is hardcoded to the binary) sets some of these variables based on the GNOME-wide gsetting values.