# How to find aliases?

Tags: command-line, shortcuts, alias

Where can I find a list/file of all aliases created in Ubuntu 17.04?
I mean shortcuts for commands most frequently used and more.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### List of defined aliases

Type `alias`, you'll get a list of all defined ones in your environment.

```
$ alias
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

---

#### List along the file they've been set in

To find the files that your aliases have been defined in, use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940611/where-is-this-environment-variable-set/940621#940621) solution, with a little bit altering it:

```
$ PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7> /tmp/mylog
$ grep "alias " /tmp/mylog | grep -e /home -e /etc
```

Which gives you a list of files, stating what `alias` defined there, the output is similar to:

```
++/home/ravexina/.bashrc> alias 'la=ls -A'
```

Which states `'la=ls -A'` has been set in my `.bashrc`.

---

#### Important files

There are many places that we can define our aliases, the most important ones might be:

- Standard ones:

  - `~/.bashrc`
  - `~/.bash_aliases`
- One of them in order:

  - `~/.bash_profile`
  - `~/.bash_login`
  - `~/.profile`
- Works but not a good place, unless you want it system wide:

  - `/etc/bash.bashrc`
  - `/etc/profile`

And any other place which get sourced while running a shell.

Comment: Witch one of the 'important files' is the best one to add a function instead of an alias? If there is one.

Comment: That would be `~/.bashrc`, However what I suggest is to create a new file: `~/.bash_functions` and put all functions there, then source that file in your `.bashrc` like: `. ~/.bash_functions`.

Comment: Before your answer I just created the file `.bash_profile` and added to `.bashrc`. I'm going to rename the file as suggested.

Comment: Remember if you use a file named `.bash_profile` then your `.profile` will not going to be sourced any more... ;)

Comment: I didn't know. I'm using `~/.bash_functions` now.

Comment: You're fine... ;)

Answer (score 5):

Aliases are defined on a per-user, per-shell basis. You can see what aliases are defined for your current shells via

```
alias
```

Read more about aliases in `man bash`.

Answer (score 1):

I might also throw in that the `.bashrc` for *new* users (not existing) is populated from `/etc/skel/.bashrc`, inside which you'll find aliases for things like `ll`, `la`, `l`, etc. So if you want every new user to have more/less/different aliases that's the place to modify them